# C++ - scanf() and printf() executing out of order

Tags: c++, scanf

I have a program that pushes ints into an array, deletes them, and sorts them. I have it set up so that the program prompts the user in each step (e.g. user chooses to add a number, program prompts for number, user enters value, program adds it, confirms, and continues).

However, `printf()` and `scanf()` are behaving strangely and out of order.

Here's an extract of the code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char op;
    int pan;
    MyList list;
    do {
        printf("a = add\nd = delete\ns = sort\nu = unsort\np = print\nq = quit\n");
        scanf("%c",&op);
        switch (op) {
            case 'a':
                printf("Enter value: ");
                scanf("%i\n", &pan);
                list.push(pan);
                printf("%i pushed\n", pan);
                break;
            case 'd':
                printf("Enter value: ");
                scanf("%i\n", &pan);
                printf("%i removed\n", pan);
                list.remove(pan);
                break;
            case 's':
                list.setSortedList(true);
                break;
            case 'u':
                list.setSortedList(false);
                break;
            case 'p':
                list.print();
                break;
            case 'q':
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("I have no idea what you want me to do.\n");
        }
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, at some points, the program seems to execute `scanf()` before `printf()` even though they're written in the other order!

Here is the result of executing the file. For convenience, lines with my own input have been appended with `<<`.

```
a = add
d = delete
s = sort
u = unsort
p = print
q = quit
a    << chose "add"
Enter value: 16    << input value
    << pressing return to see if anything changes
    << pressing it again, just in case
6    << maybe you didn't hear me, program?
16 pushed
a = add
d = delete
s = sort
u = unsort
p = print
q = quit
I have no idea what you want me to do.
a = add
d = delete
s = sort
u = unsort
p = print
q = quit
I have no idea what you want me to do.
a = add
d = delete
s = sort
u = unsort
p = print
q = quit
```

What should I do to fix this faulty execution order?

Comment: `scanf("%i\n", &pan);` why `\n`?

Comment: Stop using `scanf`, preferably.

Comment: `scanf` and `printf` are functions that come from C language, and you shouldn't use them in C++ programs. In C++, you have `std::istream` and `std::ostream` classes with `cin` and `cout` objects for such purposes.

Comment: Note that using `cin >>` is about as bad as `scanf`, so don't do that either.

Comment: remove `\n` from your scanf format string

Comment: @melpomene `cin >>` is way better if one knows  flow control of that class. Issue is that  no C++ guide I ever saw overviews that part of functionality. Stream i/o is essential on some platforms. The biggest advantage of `iostream` is type safety and portability (scanf\printf format strings aren't portable).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie You're not making much sense. The biggest advantage of iostream is `std::getline`, which is what you should be using for user input. I have no idea what you mean by flow control or portability. Type safety isn't an issue either.

Comment: @melpomene it's not only about user input. Excuse me, but `cin::getline` is inferior to  the C-style `getline` and you still need to parse input and work with C strings.   iostreams have states of streams you control and way it buffers input it guarantees that no data get lost before program would process it, if parsing error encountered, rest of data is stored in buffer and error flag is raised. iostreams are used for automated input\piping as well.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I never mentioned `cin::getline` (also, what do you mean by "C-style `getline`"?). I'm not even sure what you're arguing anymore. Do you think `FILE` objects have no buffer or state?

Comment: Sorry, `std::getline`. C-style (or POSIX) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html One should to differ between OS file buffer and program's input buffer. You would have implement the latter on your own if you need functionality of `cin`. Definition of FILE objects depends on platform also C++ streams aren't necessary implemented through those. Ofc, steam i/o and  file i/o also have own control, it's way more complicated, different platforms may have different API for that.. or some minor differences.

Comment: why would you use `scanf` and `printf` in a c++ program? Either tag the question as **C** or use `cin` and `cout` which are way better choices.

Answer (score 2):

Newbies often think that scanf reads stuff until you hit the enter key, and that it reads everything upto and including that enter key. Until you get rid of that notion you cannot understand how scanf works.

The problem is the newline at the end of your scanf format string

```
scanf("%i\n", &pan);
```

A whitespace character in a format string causes all whitespace to be consumed. So the scanf doesn't exit until you enter the next non-whitespace character, which in your case will be the next menu choice. this is why your input and output gets all out of whack.

Try this instead

```
    scanf(" %c",&op); // space before
```

and

```
    scanf("%i", &pan); // no spaces or newlines
```

By putting a space **before** the `%c` you skip any pending whitespace before you try and read the menu choice character, which is what you want.

Answer (score -3):

maybe you can add two lines in you scanf behind,
scanf ("%*[^\n]");
scanf ("%*c");

Comment: should in switch behind